# Responsive behavior for menu elements (on mobile dont show name "menu", only icon)

Tags: html, css

Due to length of company logo it is necessary to hide letters for Menu and Basket, leaving only icon visible.

All I can think of is to wrap `span` around the names (f.ex. `<div class="basket"><span>basket</span></div>`) and then use `visibility:hidden;`, but this solution leaves empty space that is visible on right sided element (basket). `display:none;` hides entire element, including icon. There must be a better way to do this with CSS... Any ideas?

```css
header {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background:forestgreen;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    height:3rem;
}

.logo {text-align:center;}
.logo span {
  display:block;
}

.menu, .basket {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/16x16');
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <div class="menu">menu</div>
        <a href="/" class="logo">Company<span>subtitle</span></a>
        <div class="basket">basket</div>
    </header>
```

Desired result:

Mobile

[image]

Desktop
[image]

Thanks in advance almighty stackoverflow society.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The minimal code necessary to reproduce your problem, belongs directly into your question, and not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: If you wrap those texts in spans that you then hide via `display:none;`, then the parent `div` won’t have a _height_ any more, so there is no area your background image icons could be displayed in. Add a height, or a padding -top then.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry for forwarding to external site... Updated the question with embeded code.

Comment: @CBroe thanks! Adding height did help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CBroe noted, in order to use `display:none;`, it is necessary to specify height, that way icons stay visible.

```css
header {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background:forestgreen;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    height:3rem;
}

.logo {text-align:center;}
.logo span {
  display:block;
}

.menu, .basket {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/16x16');
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 1rem;
}
.menu > span, .basket > span {
    display:none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
.menu > span, .basket > span {
    display:block;
}
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="menu"><span>menu<span></div>
        <a href="/" class="logo">Company<span>subtitle</span></a>
        <div class="basket"><span>basket</span></div>
    </header>
```